# Concatenation of different positions of the same variable in PHP

Tags: php, excel, concatenation, substr

I have a trouble in a php code, the problem is that I want to display the variable Cell new from the variable Cell old

$Cell old = ARI_0089_sect2

$Cell new = ARI_0089_h2 (replace 'sect' with 'h' )

all example that I found concatenate two different variables like first name and last name

I didn't find how to concatenate different position of the same variable, it is possible in microsoft excel but I didn't find how to resolve it with a php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHP function `str_replace`

```
$Cell_old = "ARI_0089_sect2";
$new = str_replace('sect', 'h', $Cell_old);
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Cell new = str_replace('sect','h',$Cell old);

echo $Cell new;
```